# Windows boots fast but loading screen on lock screen stays for long time

Tags: boot, windows-11, lock-screen

So my Windows 11 boot time is pretty fast(6.5 seconds). But there is a problem. Whenever I start my system, it boots fast, but when I enter the password it takes atleast 8-10 seconds to go to the desktop. I thought it could be corrupt windows, so I ran a scan with sfc /scannow and no corrupt files were found. I have a Nvme, and it should not be happening. No corrupt files, bloatware or any 3rd party program. I have only Chrome on it. I have disabled all the startup apps also. But no fix. Any fix?

Comment: look at startup applications , antivirus and some other apps loaded before explorer you can see wich apps are loading and you can remove startup applications to gain time on startup

Comment: Enable [Verbose Status Messages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/enable-verbose-startup-shutdown-logon-logoff-status-messages#enable-verbose-status-messages-by-using-registry-editor), which should show what step it's hanging on once you click login and can be used in conjunction with @harrymc's answer. _(I always recommend enabling verbose status messages regardless, as it makes troubleshooting login, logoff, and shutdown/reboot issues more efficient if/when they do occur)_

Comment: If my memory serves, you can use Ultimate Windows Tweaker utility (be aware though that it is not a native utility) to adjust several timeout values, not sure if this specific one is applicable but worth taking a look at if all else fails.

Comment: @K3rnel31 I have told you that there are no startup programs enabled. Last BIOS time is 5 seconds

Comment: I think this is a lock screen bug. Sometimes it is fast, and sometimes slow

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what your computer is doing during the time between
the login screen and the desktop.

The tool to use is
[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Install and run and enable menu *Options > Enable Boot Logging*,
then reboot (this will be slow).

When the desktop is shown, run Process Monitor again and analyze what
takes the time.

You may post the logfile if you would like us to take a look, but as it
may be a very large file, zip it up first.

Comment: Thanks harrymc for your suggestion. The problem was with night light. Whenever I turned on night light and restart my pc, it took a lot of time. But when I turned it off, it was very fast. Guess I have to turn on night light mode from my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Is your account local or is it a Microsoft account? If it is the latter, Windows is likely taking its time to authenticate your information over the internet, and thus, it may be a network issue. If it is local, let us know how much RAM you have and what make and model your CPU is. These could affect log in times for a local account.

Another, albeit sad as an answer, thing to consider is that the current version of Windows might just take longer to log in and hopefully this will be corrected by Microsoft soon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).